# How to use periods 2 and 3 in differential views?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I've migrated from SonarQube 6.0 to 6.2. Dashboards are dropped but the properties "period2" and "period3" still exist in the Differential Views administration section.
How can we actually use them in 6.2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. They're vestigial and will disappear "soon".